# Read all types of files in python

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer, pypdf

I am trying to extract information from different types of files in python(.pdf .doc .docx) and convert to .txt but while processing different files I am getting space and newlines when not required and many other issues. I have tried PyPDF2 and PDF manager.Please suggest me something with which i can extract information from files.

EDIT

Currently looking for something which can help me extract exact text from .pdf files. I have tried PyPDF, PDFMiner and PDF Manager and I am getting issues with some pdfs in all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think `pdfminer` is the best python module for extracting information from pdfs [Get it here](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer)

I think you can refer to    [this link](http://davidmburke.com/2014/02/04/python-convert-documents-doc-docx-odt-pdf-to-plain-text-without-libreoffice/)
for corresponding file formats.

Comment: I used pdfminer its not working for all pdfs. Moreover, can you suggest something for .doc and .docx

Comment: I think you can refer to http://davidmburke.com/2014/02/04/python-convert-documents-doc-docx-odt-pdf-to-plain-text-without-libreoffice/    for corresponding file formats.Cheers!

Comment: getting random spaces with this one as well

Comment: pdfs are difficult to parse  so there definitely would be some random spaces in place of a text that can't be parsed.So there is no perfect pdf extracter you have to choose what fits you